# Remote MariaDB access - I want IP, Maria is wanting DNS name

Tags: mariadb, remote-access

I've configured MariaDB to allow my LAN to access my Maria DB via IP addresses (e.g. 192.168.1.%).  However, when my apps make a call to the db from a **remote** machine, I'm getting rejected because Maria is getting the requesting machine's DNS name (e.g. foo.attlocal.net), NOT its IP address.  So, I added that DNS name as well.  Now, when I access Maria from the **same** machine the DB is running on, Maria is getting the DNS name foo (without the attlocal.net).  How can I stop playing wack a mole with all the DNS name combinations and just deal with IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on system variable `skip_name_resolve`.

Since it can't be changed after server start, you need to set the value either in your configuration file or pass the parameter to mysqld in start script.

Comment: Thanks! That eliminated the DNS name problem.